# Unit test for for a calss with Annotation checks using mocking

Tags: java, unit-testing, annotations, mockito

I'm trying to write a unit test for the following method, but I need to mock these too annotations using mockito? Any idea of how to do that. to check if the method is only executed for a System Admin or Administrator for that group

```
           @GET
           @Path("/")
           @HasRole(communityName = "#group", roles = "Administrator")
           @IsSystemAdministrator
           public List<Roles> listRoleMappings() {

                 List<Roles> roleMappings = roleMappingService.list(group);
                 return roleMappings;
            }
```

Comment: You can check that annotation present by reflection. Or you want to check that annotation work? If latter this is not unit test.

Comment: If this method is what you aim to test, simply ignore the annotations. Those are there for frameworks that need them. Your unit-test on the other hand, does not need them ...

Answer (score 0):

Annotations are just annotations.  They don't have behavior by themselves.  Verifying what you want will require an integration test.  The Apache CXF infrastructure provides a way to run an embedded Jetty server in a test, which you can then connect to with a WebClient.  You'll have to figure out how to mock or inject your authorization data.  I have no idea how you would do that.